# Passing parameters to controller in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am using Laravel 5 in one of my project and I want to pass some value to controller from route (**web.php**).

My code looks like:

**Route Definition:**

```
Route::get(Config::get('constant.ROUTES.UPLOADS'), 'UploadsController@index');
```

**Value of constant**

```
'UPLOADS' => '/images/{filename}'
```

**Controller**

```
class UploadsController extends Controller
{
    function index($filename) {
        //Some code here
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
ErrorException in UploadsController.php line 9:
Missing argument 1 for somewebsite\Http\Controllers\UploadsController::index()
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
function index(Request $request) {
   $filename = $request->filename; // the right value should be here
}
```

Be sure that you are using:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem exist in following line:

```
function index($filename) {
        //Some code here
}
```

Change it like:

```
public function index(Request $request, $id)
{
    $filename = $request->filename;
}
```

[Check this reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#accessing-the-request)

**Note:** To use Request:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you may also use the global request to get your value as well:

```
function index() {
        $yourFileName = $_REQUEST['filename'];
}
```